# Firebase pod installation error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, firebase-notifications

I am really stuck at this step of Firebase Installation to my iOS app.[Firebase installation to Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI0h0.png) I tried many times and finally I could install some 'pod files' to my project. But when i add `import Firebase`, error shown like

> No such module 'Firebase'

Can anyone tell me how to install firebase pod into my existing ios project ? Also how to clear the pod I just installed to it.

I am using swift 2.2, Scode 7.3 and mac os x ei

my pod content is

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target ‘APPNAME’ do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

   # Pods for APPNAME

  target 'APPNAME Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'APPNAME UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

My Error :
[image of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgFtf.png)

Comment: your pod file content ?

Comment: `# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target ‘APPNAME’ do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

   # Pods for APPNAME

  target 'APPNAME Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'APPNAME UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end`

Comment: update your question with that and use proper indentation

Comment: where you write code for Firebase? you should also pas there version like pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

Comment: @Shubhank Thank you for the suggestion. I've updated the question. Please check it.

Comment: you never added firebase pod in your podfile ?

Comment: @BhumeshPurohit can show me an example ?

Comment: @Shubhank I didn't get you.

Comment: follow the docs please.

Comment: @Shubhank Terminal seems to paused at Setting up CocoaPods master repo . Is that an error ?

Comment: @Shubhank Thank you for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This Line in your pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target ‘APPNAME’ do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
 pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
   # Pods for APPNAME

  target 'APPNAME Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'APPNAME UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

and after that update pod

Comment: Update means? build and run?

Comment: No In Terminal Write $pod install

Comment: Terminal seems to paused at `Setting up CocoaPods master repo` . Is that an error ?

Comment: Thank you... It solved my problem.. I added the code as you said and updated the pod. Terminal completed setting up CocoaPods after sometime.

Comment: The terminal seems to be paused because it was installing the pod

Comment: hello I think that you have to start with install cocoapods after that you able to install specific pod https://cocoapods.org/